# Where do i get "view" from in a compose standard project?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need this for the:

```
public abstract boolean onTouch (view v, motionevent event).
```

method.

Since i have no pre knowlege of android development i dont even know what view is.

Seems like for small apps with compose i don't need them.(Simple off topic question: do i need to learn how to use view for compose ?)

Comment: Views are Android’s built in UI system. If you are using Compose, you will not be using views except in rare occasions where you want to use a specific view widget from some library where there is no Compose counterpart, so you wrap the view to use it in Compose. It doesn’t make sense to say you specifically need to use the onTouch method of a view.

Comment: And how else can i get the touch input then ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures